# Is there a way to retrieve my LTC that did not go into my wallet?

Tags: withdrawal, green-address

Last night I tried to send LTC from my Binance account to my desktop wallet. I found out later that my wallet doesn't accept LTC so the transfer is lost. Is there any way I can retrieve it? I have the transaction ID and Blockcypher ledger with all the inputs consumed and outputs created. Is there any way I can recover my funds using that info? Green Address wallet said they can't help me, and the response from Binance is generic and non helpful. Please help?

Comment: You'll have to explain in more detail what exactly you did.  What desktop wallet software are you using?  Are you saying that you generated some address with that software which happened to work as an LTC address?  What did you do to accomplish that?

Comment: Thanks Nate, I bought the LTC on Bianace using Bitcoin. A few days later, I tried to tranfer LTC from my Binance account to my Green Address wallet. Apparently, Green Address wallets only accept Bitcoin. I simply used my Green 34 digit "receive" address and tried to send the LTC from Binance to the green wallet.

Comment: What was the first character of this address?  Would you be willing to share the transaction id?

Comment: The first character of the receive address is "3". I would prefer to send the transaction id to your email. I trust you based on your posts but I would prefer not to post it here. I have no idea if that id can be used by someone else to transfer my coins?

Comment: Nate, please see my comments below to "Evil". Is my passphrase the same as the private key?

Comment: can I use the QR code associated with that receive address in any way to recover my coins?

Comment: Ok, starting with a 3 means it's pay-to-script-hash for both coins.  The question would be whether the associated script is usable without change in a Litecoin transaction.  I don't know the answer to that, but perhaps some expert here will.  I would suggest you edit this info into your question.

Comment: thanks Nate. I'm in the process of composing a more detailed post of everything that happened and will post it later tonight. I've tried to resolve this issue with binance for days but they are unhelpful and unwilling to try and retrieve my coins. And their website has been down for over a day.

Comment: There is nothing Binance can do about this, so no need to spend any more time in that direction.  They did exactly what was asked of them by sending coins to the address you specified.  The only possible solution is to get the private key for that address (either directly from Green Address or by calculating it from your wallet seed) and see if it can be used in a Litecoin wallet to create a transaction to spend the coins.   Whether that is possible depends on whether Litecoin and Bitcoin handle P2SH scripts in the same way, which I don't know.

Comment: Nate, I heard back from Green Address, they don't store users private keys. Can you tell me how to "calculate it from my wallet seed", as you mentioned? From there I will create a Litecoin wallet and try to create a transaction. Any guidance on how to do that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

No it is lost.

Basically because the transaction is now in the LTC blockchain with a send to address that no one has the private key for.

Comment: Depending on how the address was created, there is a chance that OP actually does have the private key.  But we need more information in order to know for sure.

Comment: @NateEldredge its possible if the desktop wallet exposes the private key, to make a new LTC transaction back to the originating account. I would assume it was LTC sent to a BTCor other addess. So yeah it may be possible.

Comment: Exactly.  So I think it's premature to answer before we know more.  I voted to place the question on hold as "unclear" for this reason.

Comment: Thanks Evil and Nate, Is there a way for me to retrieve the private key? I didn't know I needed one before I tried to make the transfer. Is the private key the same as my mnemonic passphrase?

Comment: I have the original "receiving wallet" address, and the Txid, Will that be helpful?

Comment: @Kaa see if your wallet has the option to convert to a cold wallet, this should display the private and public key. You can then use those recieving addresses as originating addresses on the LTC network. If the hash is treated the same.

Comment: thanks Evil, I just emailed Green Address wallet and asked them if it's possible to convert to a cold wallet, awaiting their reply